# Firebase database observer not getting all children

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am observing my Firebase database for .childAdded. When I add a child (Dictionary to the database, it should create a snapshot of all the values to parse into a 'Task' within my app.

```
func storeTask(_ task: Task) {
    let taskInfo: [String] = [task.title, task.desc, set, due, "\(task.complete)"]
    setTaskDatabaseValue(values: taskInfo, dbChild: dbReference.child(task.title))
}

func setTaskDatabaseValue(values val: [String], dbChild db: DatabaseReference) {
    db.child("title").setValue(val[0])
    db.child("desc").setValue(val[1])
    db.child("set").setValue(val[2])
    db.child("due").setValue(val[3])
    db.child("complete").setValue(val[4])
}
```

And this is my observer method:

```
func getTasks() {
    self.dbReference.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
       let snapVal = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>

       let title    = snapVal["title"]!
       let desc     = snapVal["desc"]!
       let set      = snapVal["set"]!
       let due      = snapVal["due"]!
       let complete = snapVal["complete"]!

       let task = Task(title: title, desc: desc, set: set, due: due, complete: (complete == "true"))
       TaskController.sharedInstance.addTaskToLocalList(task)
       self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
}
```

Where getTasks() is called, in the viewDidLoad() of the view controller :

```
DatabaseController.sharedInstance.addTableView(tableView)
DatabaseController.sharedInstance.getTasks()
```

The observer method always seems to only retrieve the task title and nothing else, yet when I check the Firebase console all the information is there. Why is this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello there, did you try setting a breakpoint before creating the _task_ variable and checking whether the independent variables are being correctly filled? Maybe the problem resides in the Task object's constructor? The latter is just a speculation as to what the problem might be, will have to dig a little bit deeper into the code!

Comment: Everything seems to be working with the constructor. If I stop the app and run it again, the task will load fine, it's as though it's trying to read the data from Firebase before it's all uploaded.

Comment: At which point are you calling your `getTasks()` method? I think I can help if you share a bit more code related to your issue.

Comment: in the viewDidLoad() of the viewController containing the tableview. I'll update my question to contain the code.

Comment: Ok now that we have a little more context, are you sure you are calling your `getTasks()` method **after** calling the `storeTask(_:)` method? You mentioned in your previous comment that if you stop the app and running again, the task will load fine, so I am presuming that you are calling the methods in the wrong sequence.

Comment: Well I call the getTasks() in the viewDidLoad() of the view containing the table view. The storeTask(_:) method gets called whenever the user adds a task. I thought that the getTasks() will only run when a child is added to the Firebase database so it didn't matter if I called it first, is this not the case?

Comment: That's not exactly the case. [This event is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data). So when it's first called, it iterates over all of the child nodes first, and *then* will watch for additional child nodes to be added.